# How can I add a list in the Editor for my rotating platforms script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm currently making a 2D game and I added a platform, which is rotating around a center. Now I want, that you can choose how many platforms you want to rotate around the center. like on the screenshot with the circuit points. I'm not very keen on coding, so could you just add that to my current script pls?

Thanks!

Screenshot:
[circuit_points list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CWNv.png)

Current script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotation_Object_System : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform rotationCenter;

    public GameObject rotationObject;

    [SerializeField]
    private float rotationRadius = 2f, angularSpeed = 2f;

    public bool ClockwiseRotation;
    public bool HideRotationCenter;

    private float posX, posY, angle = 0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        Loading_Initial_Parameters();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Rotation
        posX = rotationCenter.position.x + Mathf.Cos(angle) * rotationRadius;
        posY = rotationCenter.position.y + Mathf.Sin(angle) * rotationRadius;
        rotationObject.transform.position = new Vector2(posX, posY);

        float angularMovement = Time.deltaTime * angularSpeed;

        if (ClockwiseRotation)
            angle -= angularMovement;
        else
            angle += angularMovement;

        if (angle >= 360f)
            angle = 0f;
    }

    private void Loading_Initial_Parameters()
    {
        if (rotationCenter.TryGetComponent<SpriteRenderer>(out var rotationCenterSpriteRenderer))
        {
            rotationCenterSpriteRenderer.enabled = !HideRotationCenter;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(
                $"Rotation Center ({rotationCenter.name}) does NOT HAVE " +
                $"a SpriteRenderer Component to hide/show");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a few changes will make this work for you.

1. Add a public field as a list or an array. That will allow you to add/remove elements from the inspector in Unity.
2. Update your update code to loop through each of the items in the array/list and apply the position change to each one.
3. You may need to add a little bit of code to track each rotation position individually... You're already tracking angle for a single GameObject... you would need to update that to an array/list... 1 item for each GameObject you're dealing with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, have you got some example code?